# to connect two php codes

Tags: php, html, database, postgresql

I want to connect these two php codes in such a way that if we will select any option from the drop down menu then the pie chart related to that option should be displayed for a particular row.

Code for pie chart using php and postgresql.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>Pie Chart Demo (LibChart)- https://codeofaninja.com/</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15" />
        </head>
        <body>
        <br></br>

        <?php
```

include libchart.php

```
         include "C:/xampp/htdocs/tools/libchart/libchart/classes/libchart.php";

            $chart = new PieChart( 500, 300 );
            $dataSet = new XYDataSet();
```

build a connection with postgresql

```
        $host = 'localhost';
        $port = '5432';
        $database = 'sustainable';
        $user = 'postgres';
        $password = 'postgres';
        $connectString = 'host=' . $host . ' port=' . $port . ' dbname=' . $database . 
            ' user=' . $user . ' password=' . $password;
        $link = pg_connect ($connectString);
        if (!$link)
        {
            die('Error: Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
        }
        $query = 'select * from sustainable_development';
        $result = pg_query($query);
        $i = 0;
        if($i < pg_num_fields($result))
        {
         while( $row = pg_fetch_assoc($result) ){
                    extract($row);
                    $dataSet->addPoint(new Point("{$sdg_4}", $sdg_4));
                    $dataSet->addPoint(new Point("{$sdg_5}",$sdg_5));
                    break;
                }
                $chart->setDataSet($dataSet);
                $chart->setTitle("SDG score for SDG_4 and SDG_5");
                $chart->render("1.png");
                echo "<img alt='Pie chart'  src='1.png' style='border: 1px solid gray;'/>";

            }else{
                echo "No programming languages found in the database.";
            }
        pg_free_result($result);

        ?>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Code for drop down menu using php and postgresql

```
    ?php

    $host = 'localhost';
    $port = '5432';
    $database = 'sustainable';
    $user = 'postgres';
    $password = 'postgres';

    $connectString = 'host=' . $host . ' port=' . $port . ' dbname=' . $database . 
        ' user=' . $user . ' password=' . $password;
    $link = pg_connect ($connectString);
    if (!$link)
    {
        die('Error: Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());
    }
        $query='select id, location from sustainable_development';
        $result = pg_query($query);

        echo "<html>";
        echo "<body>";
        echo "<select name='id'>";

        while ($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)) {

                      unset($id, $name);
                      $id = $row['id'];
                      $name = $row['location']; 
                      echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';

    }


        echo "</select>";
        echo "</body>";
        echo "</html>";


    ?>
```

Comment: Just do an if else statement depending on the result?

Comment: what you are trying to achieve is not just appending both code. you need to make use of jquery to update you pie chart with new data